how to disable warnings in JPAMetaModelEntityProcessor files?
How to disable all warnings in JPAMetaModelEntityProcessor files? These are automatically generated, we have no control over it. If there is a warning, like "found usage of raw type", because JPAMetaModelEntityProcessor cannot work with them properly, I just need to constantly see this warning, but cannot do anything about it. At least if I still want to use parameterized @MappedSuperclass (which I do), or if I don't disable this warning entirely (which I won't).
Similar question can be made about all generated-sources.
